# How can I add more to this command?

Tags: vimscript, command

I have been trying to make this command into a function which gets called by command, but I am not having much luck with it.

```
" Clear registers
command! WipeReg for i in range(34,122) | silent! call setreg(nr2char(i), []) | endfor
```

The aim is to add this:

```
if has ('nvim')
  :wsh!
else
  :wv!
endif
```

I use both Neovim and Vim and I can't remember these commands. Whenever use this `WipeReg` command I always have to refer to my notes to make the register clearing persistent. It would be much more convenient to have it included within the `WipeReg` command.

Comment: I don't know about Neovim, but you can tell Vim to not persist registers with `set viminfo+=<0`, so you would only need to do that cleanup once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try that:

```
function! WipeReg()
  for i in range(34,122)
    silent! call setreg(nr2char(i), [])
  endfor
  if has ('nvim')
    wsh!
  else
    wv!
  endif
endfunction

command! WipeReg call WipeReg()
```

Comment: Oh, I was so close. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback :-) Always a pleasure to help.

Comment: In recent Vims (8.1+, maybe?), you shouldn't often need the bang on `command` or `function`

Comment: [8.1.0573](https://github.com/vim/vim/commit/55d46913084745a48749d7ac4f48930852e1d87e) @D.BenKnoble; I still type it out of habit though as 15 years of that is hard to kill 